# integration bound sign change!

Tags: integration

$$\int\limits_{\pi/2}^{\pi/4}\large\frac{\cos^4x}{\sin^5x}dx=k$$

If the bound reverse, sign of the $k$ reverse as well? like this?

$$\int\limits_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\large\frac{\cos^4x}{\sin^5x}dx=-k$$

If so, could you tell me why? and if not could you tell me why not?

Thank you.

Comment: Compare [$F(b)-F(a)$] to  [$F(a)-F(b)$], $F$ being the antiderivative of whatever.

Comment: By definition, for $a<b$, $\int _b^a f=-\int_a^b f$. This proves convenient for various reasons, including the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

This convention is useful when you do substitution with decreasing function, then your limits get reversed. Look what happens when you use substitution $x = -t$
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx = - \int_{-a}^{-b} f(-t) dt = \int_{-b}^{-a} f(-t) dt
$$
If $a<b$ note that $-b<-a$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a property of every definte integral

$$\int_a^b = -\int_b^a$$

Check the list of the most important properties http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Properties